# Getting null at EventQueueMonitor.getCurrentMousePosition();

Tags: java, accessible

i am trying to make an App, with javax.accessibility. 
I have a Frame with a Panel and at this Panel is a Button. 
I made an accessibility class, included it to the accessibility.properties and made this class implements GUIInitializedListener, MouseListener

So for a Test i did this

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point mousePos = EventQueueMonitor.getCurrentMousePosition();
    Accessible accComp = EventQueueMonitor.getAccessibleAt(mousePos);
    String accName = accComp.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();
    System.out.println(accName);
 }
```

what i wanted is to become Accessible name and show it at Console.
but I allways getting mousePos=null. I dont understand what i am doing wrong.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: have you tried `e.getPoint();` to get the mouse position?

Comment: Yes, if i use e.getPoint() then i get a position, but then i become a NULL at Accessible accComp = EventQueueMonitor.getAccessibleAt(mousePos); so i do not understand why. I found an example here:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AGUItoshowaccessibleinformationcomingfromthecomponentsinan.htm    //Find the component currently under the mouse.
    Point currentPosition = EventQueueMonitor.getCurrentMousePosition();
    Accessible comp = EventQueueMonitor.getAccessibleAt(currentPosition);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found an answer.

```
Component c=(Component)e.getSource();
   Point mousePos =e.getLocationOnScreen();
    Accessible a;
    a = SwingUtilities.getAccessibleAt(c, mousePos);
```